# with out dead php script

Tags: php

I wanna run one php script by `while(true){ }`.

It will get pm which has been sent to me by other and answer them.(something like yahoo robot)

now if I set `set_time_limit(0)` and use `while(true)` and run this page on my server `http://ip-address/yahoo.php` and close my browser , Is it running for ever?

Comment: You should consider setting up a cronjob for a script like that.

Comment: @Juhana - exactly, I agree.  Running this every 5 seconds would give a quick response and save a lot of wasted processing.

Comment: Except cron has a granularity of 1 minute. You'd still need some kind of in-script loop to do the 5-second delays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ignore_user_abort(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) will probably do it

> ignore_user_abort — Set whether a client disconnect should abort script execution

Comment: False. It works as well in webservers. Try a simple `ignore_user_abort(true); sleep(20); error_log("Still alive");` script, hit with your browser, abort the connection while the sleep's active. You'll end up with "still alive" in the php error log. This would NOT happen if the script was terminated when you killed the connection.

Comment: In that case I am plain wrong in my comment (which I therefor removed), Sorry :)

Comment: This does, however, take up a process from the web server in many configurations (it's especially resource-heavy in the most common Apache+mpm_prefork+mod_php configuration). Consider running the script as a cronjob or in a terminal.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not running forever, script is terminated once you close your browser. Your whole approach is wrong, you create a daemon that runs in the background listening on a socket, it doesn't run while(true) because that's CPU cycle waste, a huge one at that.

Research about websockets and node.js, it sounds like you need similar to what's been created already.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good idea to do it this way, and should not work.
You'd better run the script  from within a shell and background it or run it in a screen.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you want a script to run forever run it in terminal (or Command Prompt).
If you close the terminal script will also stop.

Comment: not if you run the script in a screen of another easy way to background the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Try php cli, so you can run php over your Command line. 
Than you can create a Bash File which starts it, and so the Script will run "forever".

But if you start it over the Browser it will not run forever.

Answer (score 0):

No, PHP only exists as long as the request does. If you close you're browser the request will die as well.

[edit]

As other commenters clarified the [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function could help you out though.